# asp.net and input type=file multiple read data from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, multiple-file-upload, httppostedfile

I have an

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple runat="server" />
```

I don't use asp:FileUpload because I need to use a jQuery plugin for multiple image previews and for deleting images before upload them.

My question is How can I manage input data from code behind?
I have to loop through selected images. I searched on the web and I didn't find anything interesting...

If I try, from code behind to read in this way:

```
 HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["files[]"];
```

I see that Request.Files.Count is always 0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine the data should still be in the `Request.Files` collection if it was posted as part of the form.  Server-side controls or not, everything that's part of the HTTP request should be on `Request`.

Comment: I tried with  HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["files[]"]; and with  HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["files"]; but it's always null

Comment: When you debug, is there anything at all in `Request.Files`?  Examine the type before trying to assign random indexes to things.

Comment: no, count of Request.Files is 0...

Comment: If `Request.Files` is always of length 0, are you certain the files are being posted in the first place?  Check the network tab in your browser's debugging tools.  Does the request include files at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Be Honest a quick search gave me this:

In your aspx :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

In code behind :

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

    //check file was submitted
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
    }
}
```

**Update**

Another Quick Search gave me this, if you have multiple files then the solution to get them all would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
    if(file .ContentLength >0){
    //saving code here

 }
```

Comment: but I have multiple files

Comment: @Martina so add multiple within the tag? its as easy as what you do with file upload control.

Comment: If you read my question I already said that I have <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple runat="server" />

Comment: @Martina No you don't even know what are u asking? you want to manage it the input tag in your code-behind, then your answer is `HttpPostedFile` and how to parse it,

Comment: thanks Valkyriee, so the problem is that Request.Files.Count is always 0?

Comment: @Martina i would suggest you see the edit on my answer, it seems for a multiple uploads you can create a simple loop, And about the Request.Files.Count is always 0, have you tracked it? put a breakpoint and see what is the issue. you can even check if the input has a value via JQuery and alert.

Comment: the problem was that my form missing this tag enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Martina glad you found it =)